# Junit How to mock namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(" ", parameters,(ResultSet rs))

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, junit4, jacoco

i am writing test cases for repository classes were i am not able to cover some of lines in repository classes. i need to achieve 85% of code coverage and its mandatory in my case,Please suggest me something

**My actual method**

```
public Map<String, String> getProductFamily(List<String> itmNms) {

        Map<String, String> productFamilyMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
        try {
        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
        String sql = "some query";
        MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        namedParameters.addValue("itmNms", itmNms);
        productFamilyMap = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql, namedParameters, (ResultSet rs) -> {
            Map<String, String> productFamily = new HashMap<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                productFamily.put(rs.getString("ITEMNAME"), rs.getString("PRODUCTFAMILY"));
            }
            return productFamily;
        });
        }catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception in OracleRespository.getProductFamily : {}", e);
        }
        return productFamilyMap;
    }
```

**Test case for above method**

```
@Test
    public void getProductFamily() {

    List<String> itmNms = new ArrayList<String>();
    itmNms.add("A-SPK-NAMED-USER");
    oracleRepo.getProductFamily(itmNms);
    Map<String, String> mp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Assert.assertNull(mp);

}
```

By writing above test cases i am able to cover code coverage till line no 6 below lines i am not able to cover due to below statements

```
productFamilyMap = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql, namedParameters, (ResultSet rs) ->{}
```

Can some one suggest how can i achieve code coverage for above method as 100%.

Comment: Please share the test class. Do you autowire your class under test? Do you use `SpringRunner`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In cases like that, you need to "manually invoke" the code in lambda. This can be performed with `Mockito.doAnswer(...)` functionality of [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) framework. The example (suitable for Mockito 2+):

```
Mockito.doAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {

    ResultSet resultSet = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
    Mockito.when(resultSet.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
    Mockito.when(resultSet.getString("ITEMNAME")).thenReturn(...);
    Mockito.when(resultSet.getString("PRODUCTFAMILY")).thenReturn(...);

    ResultSetExtractor<Map<String, String>> resultSetExtractor = 
        invocationOnMock.getArgument(2);
    return resultSetExtractor.extractData(resultSet);

}).when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate).query(
    Mockito.anyString(), 
    Mockito.any(MapSqlParameterSource.class), 
    Mockito.any(ResultSetExtractor.class)
);
```

Then you can verify `productFamilyMap` for populated key-value pair.

If you'd still have troubles with it, you can share your code (e.g. via Github) and I'll try to help you with it.

**EDIT:** Initially, I didn't notice the thing that `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` is created manually with `new`, and it's kinda hard to mock it. In this case, it's better to refactor your production code a bit - you can create `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` object as bean (like you probably did with raw `JdbcTemplate`) and then inject it into your class (and ofc remove the line where you're creating it with `new`). Then the things become trivial.

```
@Component
public class OracleRepository {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OracleRepository.class);

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate; //created as bean in configuration class

    public Map<String, String> getProductFamily(List<String> itmNms) {

        Map<String, String> productFamilyMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
        try {
            String sql = "some query";
            MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
            namedParameters.addValue("itmNms", itmNms);
            productFamilyMap = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql, namedParameters, (ResultSet rs) -> {
                Map<String, String> productFamily = new HashMap<>();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    productFamily.put(rs.getString("ITEMNAME"), rs.getString("PRODUCTFAMILY"));
                }
                return productFamily;
            });
        }catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception in OracleRespository.getProductFamily : {}", e);
        }
        return productFamilyMap;
    }
}
```

The test class remains unchanged:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class OracleRepositoryTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private OracleRepository oracleRepo;

    @Mock
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Test
    public void getProductFamily() {
        List<String> itmNms = new ArrayList<>();
        itmNms.add("A-SPK-NAMED-USER");

        Mockito.doAnswer(invocationOnMock ->{
            ResultSet resultSet = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
            Mockito.when(resultSet.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
            Mockito.when(resultSet.getString("ITEMNAME")).thenReturn("A-SPK-NAMED-USER");
            Mockito.when(resultSet.getString("PRODUCTFAMILY")).thenReturn("SPKCLD");

            ResultSetExtractor<Map<String, String>> resultSetExtractor =
                    invocationOnMock.getArgument(2);
            return resultSetExtractor.extractData(resultSet);

        }).when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate).query(
                Mockito.anyString(),
                Mockito.any(MapSqlParameterSource.class),
                Mockito.any(ResultSetExtractor.class)
        );

        Map<String, String> productFamilyMap = oracleRepo.getProductFamily(itmNms);

        Assert.assertEquals("SPKCLD", productFamilyMap.get("A-SPK-NAMED-USER"));
    }
}
```

Comment: i am facing errors Like 
Unnecessary stubbings detected in test class: OracleRepositoryTest
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code. Also please let me the productFamilyMap i can create my own map with some values or it should be an mock object

Comment: `productFamilyMap` will be populated by the data specified in `.thenReturn(...)` methods automatically (`resultSetExtractor.extractData(resultSet)` is the code invoked under the hood in the lambda). About unnecessary stubbings - I suppose there can be a bunch of problems in the test class, and it's hard to find them like this. It's better to have [mcve] here or on github to find it quicker.

Comment: Thanks @amseager  for your quick response and Please refer to [link](https://github.com/Viswanathan24/Junit-/blob/master/OracleRepositoryTest)

Comment: i am getting unnessary stubbing issue at line 
    `when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate).query();`

Comment: @Viswanathan 's link helped me the most.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is accurate and is working. I tried in my project too.
Let me try to explain how this works.

We are saying when mocked JDBCTemplate query() method is called, then we want to invoke our own lambda expression with some mocking done, like we first create a mocked result set, and mocks some of its getString methods. Next we capture the third argument of mocked invocation which is result set extractor. Now from here we simply return this extractor extract data method with our mocked result set which will now be invoked.
So in essence we are calling the original extract data method with our mocked result set.

```
Mockito.doAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {

    ResultSet resultSet = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
    Mockito.when(resultSet.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
    Mockito.when(resultSet.getString("ITEMNAME")).thenReturn(...);
    Mockito.when(resultSet.getString("PRODUCTFAMILY")).thenReturn(...);

    ResultSetExtractor<Map<String, String>> resultSetExtractor = 
        invocationOnMock.getArgument(2);
    return resultSetExtractor.extractData(resultSet);

}).when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate).query(
    Mockito.anyString(), 
    Mockito.any(MapSqlParameterSource.class), 
    Mockito.any(ResultSetExtractor.class)
);
```